# Does WebSphere support for TLSv1.2 with Java 8 and SQL Server JDBC driver 6.0?

Tags: jdbc, java-8, websphere, tls1.2

While working on certifying TLSv1.2, and based on the below conditions:

1. The project is deployed on WebSphere 8.5.5.11 application server where only TLSv1.2 is enabled.
2. SQL server JDBC driver version 6.0 connecting to SQL Server database.
3. Java 8.

We are facing an issue with the SQL server JDBC driver and WebSphere, the driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server, the error message is : "Only TLS1.2 protocol can be enabled in SP800_131 strict mode".

Is the TLSv1.2 supported on the SQL server JDBC driver with WebSphere application server.

Pleas consider that the same project is working properly with TLSv1.2 on Tomcat application server.

part of the error :

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Only TLS1.2 protocol can be enabled in SP800_131 strict mode". ClientConnectionId:960c823d-4db9-4ac2-b2c4-2802a7b432d2
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2400)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1762)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1977)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1628)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1459)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1168)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:675)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:258)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only TLS1.2 protocol can be enabled in SP800_131 strict mode
    at com.ibm.jsse2.Q.a(Q.java:179)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.Q.b(Q.java:163)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.Q.<init>(Q.java:87)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.as.a(as.java:947)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.as.<init>(as.java:833)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:8)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1675)
```

Comment: how is your application code attempting to get the connection?  Are you directly invoking `DriverManager.getConnection()`?  In which case you'd be bypassing any DataSource configuration for WebSphere.  The full stack trace would tell us for sure.  Also, can you post the relevant Tomcat configuration for your DB/DataSource?

Comment: Looks like your SSL config in WAS is incorrect. Are you sure that you enabled correctly TLS, and not FIPS with SP800-131 mode?

Comment: Please be specific. JDBC is a Java standard, whose latest version is 4.3 (with Java 9). Talking about _"JDBC 6.0"_ is ambiguous at best (as you probably mean _SQL Server JDBC driver version 6.0_). In any case, did you try upgrading to version 6.2 of that driver?

Comment: Thank you @AndyGuibert , yes I used DriverManager.getConnection(String url) method, and regarding the tomcat , I used tomcat 8, by adding a connector to server.xml file.

Comment: Thank you @Gas,
 yes I am sure, I used the IBM documentation [Configuring TLSv1.2 for WebSphere Application Servers 8.5.5]

Comment: Thank you @MarkRotteveel, sorry for this mistake, yes I mean the SQL server JDBC.